# Retrieving encryption key from database in python PyNaCl, how do i convert back into a PublicKey or a PrivateKey object?

Tags: python, typeerror, libsodium

I'm trying to store the private/public keys as UTF-8 strings in a database. The problem is that when I bring them back into code, they are not the correct type. As bytes they print the same, as per the following code:

```
import nacl.utils
from nacl.public import PrivateKey, SealedBox
from nacl.encoding import Base64Encoder
import base64


prvkbob = PrivateKey.generate()
pubkbob = prvkbob.public_key

prvk_db = prvkbob.encode(Base64Encoder).decode('utf8')
pubk_db = pubkbob.encode(Base64Encoder).decode('utf8')

prvk = base64.b64decode(prvk_db.encode('utf8'))
shdk = base64.b64decode(pubk_db.encode('utf8'))

print(prvkbob)
print(prvk)

print(pubkbob)
print(shdk)

# It works with the original key
sealed_box = SealedBox(prvkbob)

# Error on key returned from database
sealed_box = SealedBox(prvk)
```

How do I initialize them as PublicKey or PrivateKey objects?

Answer (score 3):

I might be a little late to the party, but I ran in to the similar problem where it says:

> nacl.exceptions.TypeError: Box must be created from a PrivateKey and a
>   PublicKey

This is easily fixed by instantiation a Public or private key instance using the following lines:

```
imported_private_key = nacl.public.PrivateKey(bytes_that_are_a_key)
imported_public_key = nacl.public.PublicKey(bytes_that_are_a_key)
```

I hope it might help you or anyone else with the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Since you explicitly decoded keys in **utf-8** (`.decode('utf8')`), you must first encode those in with the very same encoding (as you did). As @DisplayName said, you just then need to instantiate `PrivateKey` and `PublicKey`

Since you plan to store the **Base64** representations of those keys, you could do the following. Here are keys generated the ways you wanted:

```py
john_private = "OSEuOrw7BDANm2b0lwddBXUxN6OFGBLBDoFbqnkdMNU="
john_public  = "bQNbTjHETLTc/RNJYa1mTDg0fQF70GsuIZFsrb43DQc="

paul_private = "ry860ekZ8T1UDTzvoPSlAVMEOjcVz3ODLYbjXfySns0="
paul_public  = "G8608AL7TE2n3P10OLS8V/8wCaf/mzflCS/5qw/TzG4="
```

The two functions work with **keys** and **messages** stored in Base64

```py
def base64_to_bytes(key:str) -> bytes: 
    return base64.b64decode(key.encode('utf-8'))

def encrypt_for_user(sender_private:str, receiver_public:str, message:str) -> str: 
    sender_private = PrivateKey(base64_to_bytes(sender_private))
    receiver_public = PublicKey(base64_to_bytes(receiver_public))
    sender_box = Box(sender_private, receiver_public)

    return base64.b64encode(sender_box.encrypt(bytes(message, "utf-8"))).decode('utf-8')

def decrypt_for_user(receiver_private:str, sender_public:str, message:str) -> str: 
    receiver_private = PrivateKey(base64_to_bytes(receiver_private))
    sender_public = PublicKey(base64_to_bytes(sender_public))
    receiver_box = Box(receiver_private, sender_public)

    return receiver_box.decrypt(base64.b64decode(message.encode('utf-8'))).decode('utf-8')
```

John sends a message to Paul:

```py
message = encrypt_for_user(john_private,paul_public,"Hi Paul, 'up?")
print(message)
9BxTezSQVlxPU5evODskj4EIb5hXqIPnkQVuhpY2qoYvcnIaBgUVhkbN8baSytsmF4RSXdI=
```

Paul decrypts it:

```py
decrypt_for_user(paul_private, john_public, message)
"Hi Paul, 'up?"
```